# How to Set Up a Particularly Wonky Membership Type?

Tags: civimember

The foundation where I volunteer has been around for 52 years and is finally adopting a CRM and I am responsible for making it work :/ I didn't even know Civicrm existed until three days ago. I'm struggling mightily on multiple fronts. I haven't slept in two days, but to stay on topic;

It has a membership type called a "Lifetime Membership". In many ways its like a layaway program. Supporters can pay as little as they like, as long as they like, on whatever regular or irregular schedule they want. On the magic day that their contributions total the membership cost, they become Lifetime Members. In theory, I guess all I need to do is keep their membership status set to "pending" until they reach the goal, which could take years. But I'm kinda fumbling between the docs, youtube videos, this forum and the crm trying to set this up. If anyone would be so kind as to give me a bullet pointed list of action items to accomplish this, I would ... I think I would cry...
Thanks

Comment: There was a bunch of discussion but i don't see any solid outcomes: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Partial+Payments+for+Event+Registrations+and+Memberships, https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14538 and https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly off beat thought on this:

- just set up a Contribution Page without any membership types, but with a special Financial Type
- use the Summary Fields extension to sum up the amount someone has paid of this type
- use CiviRules to then give the person the 'lifetime' membership.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am currently in the process of setting it up, so I haven't tested it yet. When I finally test it, I will let you know how it went :)

Comment: To be honest, I haven't tested this yet but I feel bad leaving your suggestion hanging without giving you the credit you deserve, so I'm marking it as "answered". I've finally imported all my contacts and relationships, so hopefully I will implement your suggestion soon and ask more questions if I get stuck.

Comment: Thanks. just bung any follow ups on here as comments and if appropriate i will update the Answer with more info.